# Looping through a vector, creating a new variable which is the first vector minus 2 other vectors when none of them are NA

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, na

Assuming the following dataset:

```
Company  Sales  COGS  Staff
A        100      50     25
B        200      NA    100
C         NA      50     25
D         75      50     25
E        125     100     NA
```

I would like to create a new variable called `profit` which is `Sales`- `COGS` -`Staff`, `if` neither of those variables is NA. The desired output would be as follows:

```
Company  Sales  COGS  Staff  Profit
A        100      50     25      25
B        200      NA    100      NA
C         NA      50     25      NA
D         75      50     25       0
E        125     100     NA      NA
```

I started with something like:

```
# Creating the profit column (should be unnecessary right?)
df$Profit <- NA
# For each row in the sales column/vector
for(i in df$Sales){
# If all are not NA
if(!is.na(df$Sales) & !is.na(df$COGS) & !is.na(df$Staff)){
# Do calculation for profit
df$Profit <- df$Sales - (df$COGS + df$Staff)
# If calculation not possible
} else {
df$Profit <- NA
}}
```

Which does not give an error, but it makes R go a bit haywire. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as what you see ...

```
df$Sales-df$COGS-df$Staff
[1] 25 NA NA  0 NA
```

If there is any NA in COGS and Staff result will become `NA` , just like when you do sum , there is na.rm , the simple operation mark default as `na.rm = False`

Answer (score 1):

We create a logical index with `rowSums` to check if there is any NA in one of the rows of the selected column dataset and if not, do the subtraction of the columns and assign it to 'Profit'

```
i1 <- !rowSums(is.na(df1[-1]))
df1$Profit[i1] <- with(df1, (Sales-COGS-Staff)[i1])
df1
#  Company Sales COGS Staff Profit
#1       A   100   50    25     25
#2       B   200   NA   100     NA
#3       C    NA   50    25     NA
#4       D    75   50    25      0
#5       E   125  100    NA     NA
```

NOTE: It is a general way to exclude the NA rows and it thus we do the calculation only a subset of rows instead of the whole dataset

But, any value substracted with `NA` returns NA, so using

```
df1$Profit <- with(df1, (Sales - COGS - Staff))
```

should also work

---

Or another option if there are many columns,

```
rowSums(df1[-1] * c(1, -1, -1)[col(df1[-1])])
```

Comment: I am pretty sure this solution is going to come in handy later. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This seems a job for `within`.

```
df <- within(df, Profit <- Sales - COGS - Staff)

df
#  Company Sales COGS Staff Profit
#1       A   100   50    25     25
#2       B   200   NA   100     NA
#3       C    NA   50    25     NA
#4       D    75   50    25      0
#5       E   125  100    NA     NA
```

**DATA.**

```
df <- read.table(text = "
Company  Sales  COGS  Staff
A        100      50     25
B        200      NA    100
C         NA      50     25
D         75      50     25
E        125     100     NA
", header = TRUE)
```